# How to keep my Minecraft server running in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, minecraft-forge

I used a VM in Google Cloud Platform to host a Minecraft server, which I use `./run.sh` to start the server. However, once I close the VM bash it shuts down my server. It's a way to keep my server running?

I tried using `screen -S run.sh` it didn't work though.

Comment: You would probably want to install the Minecraft Server's daemon or run it as a service. The screen application should work in a pinch to run the command detached from the main process. 

Try running the following:
1. `screen`
2. `./run.sh`
3. ( Ctrl+a + d) [To detach]

then exit the console